# Auto-complete not working in VSCode GraphQL extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql

I struggle to get the VSCode GraphQL extension to work, more precisely its auto-complete feature.
I configured the extension with the url to my GraphQL server (opening it in the browser opens Playground which I enabled):

```
//graphql.config.js
module.exports = {
  extensions: {
    endpoints: {
      default: {
        url: "http://<my_url>:3000/graphql",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and the schema doesn't seem to get loaded. The auto-complete in ``` gql`` ```  is not working and what I can see in the extension output is:

```
9/25/2021, 6:52:35 PM [4] (pid: 18905) graphql-language-service-usage-logs: {"type":"usage","messageType":"initialize"}
(node:18905) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:18905) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
is in debug mode: false
is in debug mode: false
(node:18905) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
[Error - 6:52:39 PM] Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed with message: A cached document cannot be found.
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 6:52:40 PM] Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed with message: A cached document cannot be found.
  Code: -32603
```

Any idea what is the issue? All help appreciated!